# How do I view JSON files in a nice format?

Tags: json

This may be a really dumb question...I've got some JSON files (downloads of chat histories from Facebook, etc.). I can open the files up fine but they're in the "raw" format which doesn't make them easy to read.

Is there a way I can display these files in a more friendly format please? Better still, to be able to copy and paste chat history into a more familiar bit of software such as Word etc.?

Thank you.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, but any programming IDE will have an extension to pretty-print JSON. The alternative if you don't have one is an extension for Notepad++ or Firefox.

Comment: I agree this is off-topic, but you can have a look at browser extensions to view JSON files like:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-viewer/gbmdgpbipfallnflgajpaliibnhdgobh